# What is the correct way to standardize sparse data?

Tags: standardization

Suppose that I have a column of data with lot of zeros. What is the correct way to standardize the data?

To be concrete assume a vector of 100 elements whose first three elements are 1, 2, and 3 and the rest are 0s like so: x = [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, ...0].

Then do we standardize the 0s as well or leave them as 0s and simply standardize the non-zero values?

Comment: I think it really depends on the domain of the problem. What do the $0$'s signify? Missing data or real zeros? Do you have only one observation of the signal? Do you have any assumptions on the coordinates that are not zero?

In other words - why do you want to normalize?

Comment: Real zeros. I have several such sparse columns where the non-zero values vary widely. They can vary by several orders of magnitude. I would like to find a principled way to bring all of them to the same scale so that I can develop some predictive models.

Comment: What is the reason that you want to normalize?

Comment: @MichaelChernick I have a lot of features and was thinking of using PCA to reduce dimensions. In addition, I believe that some methods such as the lasso require normalization.

Comment: Wait, so the sparsity is in the columns or in the rows? I really don't understand the setup, what is the data, and what you are trying to predict.

Answer (score -1):

I have problem with sparse data some days ago. I thinked about this too. The first point is think about what that numbers represents. In my case i just use to make a bag of words and the vectors of words are too large more that 5000 columns with some numbers and a loot of zeros.

For a linear model is good make the variables have the same range. So you can make a standardization in your data this make the mean by 0, std = 1 and var=1. But this will not make you data by in the same range so you will need reescale for -1 to 1 interval.

This work well for sparse data with not to high diference in the max values of the same variable.